# Java transform ArrayList of type object to another ArrayList of type object

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-stream

I have a class with member variables:

```
class Filter{
  private String key;
  private String operator;
  private Object value;
}
```

And List of Type Filter as below:

```
[
{
  key: status,
  operator:equal,
  value: active
},
{
  key: status,
  operator:equal,
  value: inactive
},
{
  key: name,
  operator:equal,
  value: jhon
},
{
  key: id,
  operator:equal,
  value: 123
}
]
```

I want to transform the above `List` into a new `List` as below where if the key is same  `key: status`
then in new list need to have only one entry with value is in list type  `value: [active, inactive]`
and operator will be `IN`

```
[
{
  key: status,
  operator:in,
  value: [active, inactive]
},
{
  key: name,
  operator:equal,
  value: jhon
},
{
  key: id,
  operator:equal,
  value: 123
}
]
```

What is the best and efficient way to achieve this solution, preferably using Java 8 stream and lambdas?
Wanted to avoid traditional for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.partitioningBy` to split the `List` into two parts based on whether or not the Filter's key is `"status"`. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/wcI8Mq)</sup>

```
final Map<Boolean, List<Filter>> parts = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(f -> "status".equals(f.getKey())));
final Object[] statuses = parts.get(true).stream().map(Filter::getValue).toArray();
final List<Filter> result = parts.get(false);
if (statuses.length != 0) {
    result.add(0, new Filter("status", "in", statuses));
}
```

For multiple keys, you can use `Collectors.groupingBy`. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/em5lAF)</sup>

```
final Map<String, List<Filter>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Filter::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
final List<Filter> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1
                ? new Filter(e.getKey(), "in", e.getValue().stream().map(Filter::getValue).toArray())
                : e.getValue().get(0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks @hev1 for quick response and suggestion, status was one example but there would be n number of other key similar to status which will have different values. For example  Key "department" , value : "dept1" and key : department , value : dept2, So I might not be knowing what are the same keys available with different values .

Comment: Thanks @hev1, I think, I have to change the type of value member to List<Object> instead of Object. As even after transformation, I could not able to retrieve value.                      ex - result[Filter [key=status, operator=in, value=[Ljava.lang.Object;@1c80dae9], Filter [key=name, operator=equal, value=abc]]                                                           Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: @ManojKumar Did you try the demo I provided? It is certainly still possible to retrieve the results.

Comment: For some security reason I could not able to open demo link "https://ideone.com/wcI8Mq".. getting message Your Internet access is blocked Firewall or antivirus software may have blocked the connection.

Comment: @ManojKumar Try this code: https://pastebin.com/RXW9y3As

Comment: Thanks a lot @hev1. I could able see the sample now ..

Answer (score 2):

First, create a class for your response with List of `value`

```
class FilterRes{
  private String key;
  private String operator;
  private List<Object> values;
  // getter setter constractor
}
```

Now first transform `Filter` into `FilterRes` using `map()` then collect as map using `Collectors.toMap` and merge group in merge function. Then  get the values in an ArrayList

```
Map<Integer, FilterRes> resMap = list.stream()
                .map(s -> new FilterRes(s.getKey(), s.getOperator(),
                                        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.getValue()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(FilterRes::getKey, e -> e,    
                                    (a, b) -> new FilterRes(a.getKey(), "in", 
                                                Stream.concat(a.getValue().stream(),
                                                              b.getValue().stream())
                                                         .collect(Collectors.toList()))));

List<FilterRes> resList= new ArrayList(resMap.values()); // Create list from map values
```

Comment: Thanks  @User - Upvote don't say Thanks.. How you are handling the operator varible to make it "IN" instead of "equal"

Comment: Thanks  a lot @User - Upvote don't say Thanks it was really very helpful for me.